# Binding as a formatted string

Tags: wpf, data-binding, string-formatting

I have a ListBox which hold a set of objects (linked via ItemsSource bind to an ObservableCollection). I haven't used Dynamic binding yet. It currently use the `ToString()` method of the object. The ToString() method shows a string this way : `name (someOtherProperty)`

However, **even if the INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented and that i use an ObservableCollection**, **if i change an item property this string won't be updated**.

I believe that this is because it only calls `ToString` once. instead i guess i have to use data binding but *how* i can form such a string with it ? << name (someOtherProperty) >>

Thanks.

Comment: Your assertion that it will call the `ToString` method just once, because it never receives a PropertyChange notification that would cause it to recall it.  I think you can force it to call `ToString` again by doing a `PropertyChanged(null)` which tells it to check all bindings again.  Beyond that, I don't understand the rest of your question.

Comment: @CodingGorilla: This won't do since there is no binding to begin with, the method just gets executed and that't it.

Comment: Yea, that's why I said "I think...", I wasn't sure but thought it might be worth a try.  Seems like for some reason he can't or doesn't want to bind to a proper property.

Comment: What i want to do is show two properties instead of just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a multibinding, e.g. something like this:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} ({1})">
    <Binding Path="name"/>
    <Binding Path="someOtherProperty"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

If you just let it execute ToString there is no proper binding at all, any notifications will have no effect.

You use it like this:

```
<ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <!-- The above binding here -->
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Where do i have to set this ?

Comment: Can you update your question to show the actual binding XAML, then we can help you format it properly to use the `MultiBinding`.

Comment: There has to be _some_ binding or it wouldn't display anything!

Comment: @CodingGorilla: No, if you do not speciify anything ToString is called, that's the issue here.

Comment: @CodingGorilla : Im sorry but H.B. is right there is no binding.. i am only setting the itemsSource to the observableCollection so the tostring is called once that all. I just didn't know how to bind more than one property to the same element.

Comment: @H.B. Sorry for the delay. Thanks for your solution. This work like a charm !